# Tag Synonyms on Low Use Tags

Tags: feature-request, reputation, tag-synonyms

Some tags have a very low use level, and therefore practically no-one has the score to vote on synonyms for it.  For example, the SO [image-resizing](/questions/tagged/image-resizing) tag.  There is a synonym in the queue: [image-resize](/questions/tagged/image-resize).  Because it's such a low-use tag, almost no-one can vote on it.

Possible solutions:

1. Vary the score required to vote by how much the tag is used
2. Allow users with enough score in related tags to vote
3. Allow Trusted Users (20k) to create synonyms regardless of usage

Comment: Agreed: see tags 'significant-digits' and 'significant-figures' on SO.  I have set the wheels in motion for 'significant-figures' to be a synonym of 'significant-digits', but no-one except a moderator is likely to be able to make that formal (13 questions total under significant-digits, now).

Comment: If find it bizzar that you can't even suggest a synonym without 5 reputation points let a lone vote for one. For instance I just noticed 'color' and 'colour' both exist seperatly but can't do anything about it.

Comment: This is still an irritating problem.  I'm proposing this be a feature-request.

Comment: Why not just pick lest used tag and retag all the questions to the more popular tag. The less popular tag will then get autodeleted but the system once it has no questions. It's usually the case that folks create a question on the site meta allowing people to vote on this retagging before it happens.

Answer (score 5):

3. Get a moderator to do it.

Comment: Community smell.

Comment: How exactly do you do that?

Comment: Usually after posting a [discussion] question on Meta and seeing if the community agrees, @MartinBrown.

Comment: @mmyers: Creating a discussion on Meta for a little-used tag that is obviously a synonym may be a bit too much work for the less industrious among us. Cf. [tag:rhotic] and [tag:rhoticity] on *English*. It would at least be nice if there were a flag button on the synonym-suggestion page itself.